# Custom function returning #Value

Tags: vba

I have a set of data that I need to create a weighted average for, so I create a custom function.

However, there is some weird behavior that I can't figure out. 
First, when the function calculates in a routine, it returns #VALUE.  I intentionally, look for strings or empty cells, the calculation works fine until the last line where I return it, then it fails.

Additionally, after I click `the active cell > click the address bar > press enter` it calculates correctly.  I figured I just hit the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f9</kbd> shortcut or the workbook had auto recalculate off, however, that is not the case. It is configured correctly.

Also weirdly, it seems the calculation runs the function 3 TIMES.

The data looks like this.  Top row is row 8, bottom is 25

```
 N              O       p   Q    R
 6,392        8,732     -   -   88.9%
 5,832       11,426     -   -   91.8%
 3,206        6,174     -   -   86.7%
 20,610      13,803     -   -   72.5%
 2,185        2,794     -   -   86.3%
 4,859        5,129     -   -   82.3%
 753          1,003     -   -   84.6%
 1,565        2,537     -   -   98.0%
 766          1,067     -   -   99.0%
 773            737     -   -   95.4%
 228            455     -   -   93.9%
 19               0     -   -   
 20              35     -   -   77.2%
 0                0     -   -   99.5%
 39             145     -   -   91.0%
 130              0     -   -   91.2%
 724            359     -   -   96.7%
 $48,101                        [=wAvg(R8:R24,-4))]
```

The function looks like this:

```
Public Function wAvg(valueRange As Range, weightOffset As Integer) As Variant

    Dim weightedAverage As Double
    Dim values As Range
    Dim totalWeights As Long
    Dim weightColOffset As Long
    weightColOffset = weightOffset

    weightedAverage = 0
    Set values = valueRange

    Dim value As Range

    totalWeights = ActiveCell.Offset(0, weightColOffset).value

    For Each value In valueRange
        Dim weight As Double
        weight = value.Offset(0, weightColOffset) / totalWeights
        If (CStr(value) <> "") Then
        weightedAverage = weightedAverage + weight * value.value
        End If
    Next value

    wAvg = weightedAverage
End Function
```

Am I returning this right or mismatching types? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Why not use **=SumProduct** to calculate the weighted average?

Comment: Good idea. Far simpler. I just hadn't realized I could use that.

Comment: `ActiveCell` may not be the cell that the formula is in - it could be a cell on a different sheet when it recalculates.  To reference the cell that the formula is in use `Application.Caller`. As an example - `R8` is a formula `=Sheet2!A1`.  You change that value and the function fires (it's not a volatile function so had to change something that would make it recalculate) - your activecell is on a different sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AlexP said - `SUMPRODUCT` is probably better.

For your original code this may be better.
`Application.Caller` will always reference your formula cell, so will always return the $48,101 value.

```
Public Function wAvg(ValueRange As Range, WeightOffset As Integer) As Double

    Dim rCell As Range 'Individual cell in ValueRange.
    Dim Weight As Double
    Dim WeightedAverage As Double


    For Each rCell In ValueRange
        Weight = 0
        If rCell <> "" Then
            Weight = rCell.Offset(, WeightOffset) / Application.Caller.Offset(, WeightOffset)
            WeightedAverage = WeightedAverage + Weight * rCell
        End If
    Next rCell

    wAvg = WeightedAverage

End Function
```

This kind of stuff isn't needed:
`Set values = valueRange`.  `valueRange` already holds the correct range, so just use that.
`weightedAverage = 0`.  At the start of your code this will already be 0.

Comment: Just a sidemark... If it still runs three times, you could set Application.EnableEvents to False and Application.Calculation to xlManual before the for each loop and reverse that after the for each loop (true and xlAutomatic).